# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "image" of relation "choices_keyword" already exists

Tags: django

I have an issue between two migrations below. As you see the below code, they have `migrations.AddField(... name='image', ...)` in common. Because of that, they throw the below error every time I run `manage.py migrate`.

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "image" of relation "choices_keyword" already exists.

Just to solve that issue temporarily, I have to run `manage.py migrate --fake` then it's working, but I know using -fake everytime is not a proper way. How can I solve that issue?

**0015_auto_20190404_0925.py**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('choices', '0014_auto_20190111_1625'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='keyword',
            name='image',
            field=imagekit.models.fields.ProcessedImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=modvisor.choices.models.image_path),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='keyword',
            name='status',
            field=models.CharField(choices=[('inactive', 'Inactive'), ('active', 'Active')], default='inactive'),
        ),
    ]
```

**0015_keyword_image.py**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('choices', '0014_auto_20190111_1625'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='keyword',
            name='image',
            field=imagekit.models.fields.ProcessedImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=modvisor.choices.models.image_path),
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is you are having 2 migrations in the same app with the same serial number 0015.

To fix it, follow these steps

- delete the latest migration file `0015_auto_20190404_0925.py` or `0015_keyword_image.py` you would know better
- Do makemigration. `python manage.py makemigration <app_name>`
- Do migrate.`python manage.py migrate <app_name>`

Comment: Yes it is safe, provided the migration is not executed in the DB